# How can I change the line for long table footnotes?

Tags: threeparttable

I am trying to align the table footnote with the table. But, I am not successful. The following is my code. I also attached the captured file. Can somebody help me to figure out this?

```
\begin{table} 
\caption{Unconditional moments of consumption and assets} \label{Tab2}
\vspace{0.3in}
\begin{spacing}{0.8}
{\footnotesize Table 2 presents the annualized consumption and asset moments for different models with different settings. Target values for the consumption and asset moments are obtained by the U.S. data from 1960 to 2015. To estimate the model-implied the consumption and asset moments, 1,000 sample paths of the model are simulated. Each path consists of 600 monthly frequency. The mean value of each moment is calculated across time and paths. Model 1 is the simplest representative agent model without labor income. Model 2 is the representative agent model with labor income. Model 3 is the homogeneous multiple agents model with labor income. Model 4 is the heterogeneous agents model with labor income but without short-selling constraint. Finally, the base model mainly analyzed in this paper is the heterogeneous agents with labor income and short-selling constraint.}
\end{spacing}
\vspace{0.3in}

\begin{threeparttable}

\resizebox{6.5in}{!}{


\begin{tabular}{lcccccccc}

    \T \B   Input/Moment &   &  & U.S. data & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Model}        \\ 
        \cline{5-9} 
     \T \B   & & & & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4 & Base \\ \cline{1-9} \\ [-1.5ex]
       \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: Model input and specification}} \\ 
        \T $\#$ of agents $N$ & & & & 1 & 1 & 50 & 50 & 50 \\
        $[\gamma_1, \ \gamma_N]$ & & & & 20.5\tnote{1} & 20.5 & 20.5 & [1, 40] & [1, 40] \\
        Labor income & & & & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
              \B  Constraint & &  & & No & No & No & No & Yes  \\ 
                    \\

         \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textbf{Panel B: Consumption moments}} \\               
          \T Aggregate consumption growth mean & & & 0.0180 & 0.05 & 0.0137 & 0.0137 & 0.0138 & 0.0138 \\     
        \B  Aggregate consumption growth st. dev. & & & 0.0137 & 0.09 & 0.0305 & 0.0305 & 0.0307 & 0.0307 \\          \\ 
          \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textbf{Panel C: Asset returns moments}} \\        
         \T  Equity excess return mean & & & 0.0617 & 0.1661\tnote{2} & 0.05 & 0.0471 & 0.0245 & 0.0235 \\     
          Equity excess return st. dev. & & & 0.1525 & 0.0900 & 0.2516 & 0.2371 & 0.2246 & 0.2196 \\   
                   Sharpe ratio & & & 0.4048 & 1.8450 & 0.1986 & 0.1986 & 0.1090 & 0.1071 \\   
                   Risk-free rate mean & & & 0.0145 & -0.6600 & 0.3607 & 0.3607 & 0.2304 & 0.2312 \\ 
                                      Risk-free rate st. dev. & & & 0.0266 & 0 & 0.0009 & 0.0008 & 0.0011 & 0.0012 \\ 
       \B $Corr(dR_t,\frac{d\sum_{i=1}^{N}C_{i,t}^*}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}C_{i,t}^*})$ & & & 0.1921 & 1 & 0.0502 & 0.0473 & 0.0481 & 0.0473 \\ \hline


    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{tablenotes}
 \footnotesize
\item[1] 20.5 is chosen as the average of [1,40]
\item[2] If the moments of aggregate consumption growth (0.018, 0.0137) are used, the asset moments from excess returns mean to risk-free rate mean are 0.0039, 0.0137, 0.2817, and 0.4271, respectively. 
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
\clearpage
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Please don't post code fragments. Instead edit your question to include the fragment in a complete compilable document that people can play with. For example, you have no definition for `\B` and `\T` in your code.

Comment: The problem is your `\resizebox` command. This is something you shouldn't do. Instead make your first column a fixed width column to reduce the width of your whole table.  You might also want to use the `booktabs` package to make the table cleaner.

Comment: Do post your code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution without `\resizebox`, but with `booktabs` to have some vertical padding aroung the rules. Not knowing what `\B` and `\T` do, I neutralised them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, threeparttable, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath, setspace}
\DeclareMathOperator{\corr}{Corr}
\newcommand\T{\relax}
\newcommand\B{\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Unconditional moments of consumption and assets} \label{Tab2}
  \vspace{3ex}
  \begin{spacing}{0.8}\footnotesize
    \footnotesize Table 2 presents the annualized consumption and asset moments for different models with different settings. Target values for the consumption and asset moments are obtained by the U.S. data from 1960 to 2015. To estimate the model-implied the consumption and asset moments, 1,000 sample paths of the model are simulated. Each path consists of 600 monthly frequency. The mean value of each moment is calculated across time and paths. Model 1 is the simplest representative agent model without labor income. Model 2 is the representative agent model with labor income. Model 3 is the homogeneous multiple agents model with labor income. Model 4 is the heterogeneous agents model with labor income but without short-selling constraint. Finally, the base model mainly analyzed in this paper is the heterogeneous agents with labor income and short-selling constraint.
  \end{spacing}
  \vspace{4ex}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X*{7}{c}}
      \multirow{2}{*}{\T \B Input/Moment} & \multirow{2}{*}{U.S. data} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Model} \\
      \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){3-7}
      \T \B & & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4 & Base \\
      \midrule
      \multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{\textbf{Panel A: Model input and specification}} \\
      \addlinespace[0.8ex]
      \T $\#$ of agents $N$ & & 1 & 1 & 50 & 50 & 50 \\
      $[\gamma₁, \ \gamma_N]$ & & 20.5\tnote{1} & 20.5 & 20.5 & [1, 40] & [1, 40] \\
      Labor income & & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
      \B Constraint & & No & No & No & No & Yes \\
      \\
      \multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{\textbf{Panel B: Consumption moments}} \\
      \addlinespace[0.8ex]
      \T Aggregate consumption growth mean & 0.0180 & 0.05 & 0.0137 & 0.0137 & 0.0138 & 0.0138 \\
      \B Aggregate consumption growth st. dev. & 0.0137 & 0.09 & 0.0305 & 0.0305 & 0.0307 & 0.0307 \\ \\
      \multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{\textbf{Panel C: Asset returns moments}} \\
      \addlinespace[0.8ex]
      \T Equity excess return mean & 0.0617 & 0.1661\tnote{2} & 0.05 & 0.0471 & 0.0245 & 0.0235 \\
      Equity excess return st. dev. & 0.1525 & 0.0900 & 0.2516 & 0.2371 & 0.2246 & 0.2196 \\
      Sharpe ratio & 0.4048 & 1.8450 & 0.1986 & 0.1986 & 0.1090 & 0.1071 \\
      Risk-free rate mean & 0.0145 & -0.6600 & 0.3607 & 0.3607 & 0.2304 & 0.2312 \\
      Risk-free rate st. dev. & 0.0266 & 0 & 0.0009 & 0.0008 & 0.0011 & 0.0012 \\
      \B $\corr\Bigl(dR_t,\frac{d∑_{i=1}^{N}C_{i,t}^*}{∑_{i=1}^{N}C_{i,t}^*}\Bigr)$ & 0.1921 & 1 & 0.0502 & 0.0473 & 0.0481 & 0.0473 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize\smallskip
      \item[1] 20.5 is chosen as the average of [1,40]
      \item[2] If the moments of aggregate consumption growth (0.018, 0.0137) are used, the asset moments from excess returns mean to risk-free rate mean are 0.0039, 0.0137, 0.2817, and 0.4271, respectively.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask a follow-up question? Then, in this code, how do I resize the table to fit to the page? I cannot find something in this code that works like 'resize'.

Comment: @chanik: You don't have to: `tabularx` uses a length as a first argument, and I set it to `\linewidth`, so it  automatically fits the page, unless some contents overflows its cell, which is not the case. Resizing a table is bad practice, as it often leads to unreadable tables.